# What is the probability that a third randomly chosen real number is between two earlier randomly chosen real numbers?

Tags: probability

Question 1:  Suppose you pick three random real numbers A, B and C all at the same time.

Are the following outcomes all equally likely or are some more likely than others?

A < B < C

A < C < B

B < A < C

B < C < A

C < A < B

C < B < A

Question 2:  Suppose you pick two random real numbers A and B and it happens that A < B.  Next, you pick a third random real number C.

What is the probability that A < C < B?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: It seems the answer to the first question is yes and the answer to the second question is 0 since there is only a finite distance between A and B.

Comment: @michael35 Do you think it matters for the order the 3 numbers will be in whether we pick the 3 numbers at the same time or one after the other? Or whether we pick all 3 at once but reveal them one at a time?

Comment: That's basically my question.

Comment: Ok, what if we pick A, B, and C at the same time, but first reveal A and C before revealing B ... do you know think that the probability that B is between A and C is also 0?

Comment: By "random real numbers" do you mean that they are uniformly distributed in $(-\infty , \infty)$

Comment: Yes, a uniform distribution

Comment: @Bram28 No, I would think the probability that B is between A and C is 1/3 in that case

Comment: @michaelc35 But if we first pick and immediately reveal A and C, and then later pick B, you think it has a probability of 0 of being between A and C, right?

Comment: Yes though I'm not sure :)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. You can't choose real numbers uniformly at random.

Comment: Perhaps you begin by picking numbers uniformly distributed on $(-N,N)$ and then take the limit as $N \to \infty$

Comment: There is a chance that C could be between A and B in question 2 since there are numbers between A and B - the probability is not zero - still it seems you could say it is 'almost surely' not between A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your dilemma. On the one hand we have:

**Argument 1**

It does not matter whether you pick all three numbers at once or one at a time. For example, suppose we pick three numbers A,B,D all at once, but reveal only two of A and B. And, also suppose that after we have revealed A and B, we pick a new number C.

Now, it makes little sense to think that the probability of D being between A and B would be any different than the probability of C being between A and B: the only difference is that one number was picked before the reveal, and the other after the reveal, and of course the picking of a number is not going to be affected by the reveal.

Also, as the first question makes clear, the probability that D is between A and B is $\frac{1}{3}$ .. so therefore the probability that C is between A and B is also $\frac{1}{3}$

But on the other hand we have:

**Argument 2**

Whatever A and B are, their difference is finite, and hence any third random number has a $0$ probability of being between them.

... so ... maybe this is a reductio ad absurdum against the very assumption that we can randomly pick numbers from all real numbers with equal likelihood?

Comment: Yes, randomly choosing a real number is not well defined. A uniform distribution requires a finite width. There do exist probability functions on the reals, so if you specify one of those then your question will be answerable.

Comment: There are infinitely many pairs A and B to be integrated over.

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** choose a real number at random with **uniform** probabilities. However, there are various probability distributions you can choose from. Assuming you choose one of these PDFs, then for question one, all the possible orderings are equally probable because you are choosing them **independently** or **all at the same time**. For the second question the probability of A < C < B completely depends on the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Let A, B and C be uniformly distributed on $(-N,N)$

Then each has pdf = $\frac 1{2N}$

The probability $A<C<B$ is given by

$$ \begin{eqnarray} P = & &\frac 1 {(2N)^3}\int_{-N}^N\int_A^N\int_A^B dC \; dB \; dA
\\=&&\frac 1 {(2N)^3}\int_{-N}^N  \int_A^N\  (B-A)\; dB \; dA
\\=&  & \frac 1 {(2N)^3}\int_{-N}^N  ( \frac 12 N^2-AN)-(\frac 12 A^2-A^2     )    \; dA 
\\=& & \frac 1 {(2N)^3}\int_{-N}^N  (\frac 12 A^2-AN+ \frac 12 N^2 )    \; dA 
\\= & &\frac 1 {(2N)^3}  (\frac 13 N^3 +N^3) \\ = & &\frac 16  \end{eqnarray} $$

This result is independent of $N$ so you would expect it to apply in the limit $N \to \infty$